# Creating a shortcut to run an automated test

Tags: c#, visual-studio, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests, shortcut-file

For simplicity's sake, I am wanting to create a desktop shortcut that when clicked, runs an automated C# Test Method that I have created. That way, when the icon is clicked, the test will be run without Visual Studio.

Could anyone provide me with some guidance as how to accomplish this, if it is even possible for me to do? I'd appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: by test method you mean NUnit test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [invoke MSTest from the command line](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489.aspx):

```
mstest /testcontainer:tests.dll /test:mytest
```

Comment: Likewise there's an [NUnit command line test runner](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Console-Command-Line).  Once you figure out the command line to use, store it in a bat file.  Then use the bat file as your shortcut for running your test.